# Is there a way to change latex to be able to write less curly braces in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, braces

The markup for complex expressions in latex often gets very big, unreadable and hard to edit. I feel it could be better, at least sometimes. Maybe I don't understand something about parsing, and I surely don't know some historical details, but just looking at it, I don't see why `2^{2^n}` couldn't just be `2^2^n` or why `\frac{\frac12}{\frac34}` couldn't be `\frac\frac12\frac34`. You know, just eat the arguments from right to left. Is there something I can do to have something like that?

Comment: ...except TeX does not digest arguments from right to left...

Comment: `\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{3}{4}}` is way more readable.

Comment: @egreg and unambiguous.

Comment: And what would you do with `\frac{123}{456}`?

Comment: @egreg Sorry, I should've been clearer. Surely someone who doesn't know tex will understand that easier. But when there are so many braces in more complex formulas it gets harder for me because I have to move my eyes so much. But my actual priority is speed of input and modification rather than readability of code.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I know it doesn't that's why I'm asking for a way to change that. I don't know, maybe some kind of command that would translate from my dream syntax to normal TeX.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ideally I'd probably want the arguments to be separated by whitespace, like `\frac 123 456` (that would change the ones in my post)

Comment: @acupoftea if you want to do this I would drop the psuedo-tex syntax such as `\frac` and just specify a language (actually you might like the existing [asciimath](http://asciimath.org/) syntax) and then transform that to tex (in the case of asciimath there are existing translators)

Comment: "translate from my dream syntax" is the goal of every programming language.  The fact that there are so many shows how hard of a problem that is.  It would be possible to use whitespace instead of `{}`, but at the moment whitespace is very useful as a way to make complex formulas easier to read.  If whitespace delimits tokens, then would anything be left to spread things out?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is it then possible to nicely embed such a thing into documents? Did someone already implement that?

Comment: @acupoftea you would have to pre-process the documents, people regularly use markdown (and perhaps with asciimath-like math syntax) and generate a tex document look at r-markdown or pandoc or ..... Or you could just write it in your editor setup. _If_ you specified a grammar for the input (I wouldn't like to guess one from your scary \frac example:-) then you could parse that in emacs lisp so when editing the file in emacs it could expand inline, but personally I'd find the input just completely confusing

Comment: Using white space to separate the arguments will only work if you don't have white space in the arguments. Your idea will perhaps make simple expressions easier to parse, but not complex ones as you would have to count  the white spaces very carefully - there is a reason why also printed math has lots of parentheses.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I don't understand, what do you mean by "white space in the arguments"? Can you give an example? Something like `\frac \frac 10 20 \frac 30 40` seems to work if you just read it stack-based right to left.

Comment: @acupoftea what would be the arguments to `\frac` in `$\frac \mylocalcommand 123 \myothercommnd 4$` ?  Presumably your answer would be that it depends on the definitions of the local commands, which would mean that there would be essentially no hope of getting good syntax highlighting or context sensitive help in the editor as the editor would have to parse in-document definitions in order to give any syntax  help.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's a good point, you know, I didn't mean to design a new language, just throwing ideas in hopes something similar already exists. Perhaps this could be alleviated by separating commands into objects and functions like some programming languages already have. Or just let it be a tradeoff.

Comment: Spaces are used all the time in math to make the code more readable. I type `x + y ` not `x+y`,  `\int f(x) dx`, `x \leftarrow y`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But it's Turing complete, so shouldn't there be some way to translate one into the other? Even with things like luatex?

Comment: turing completeness doesn't help here, that just says that you could emulate a tex-like system that had a different parsing model than texs using tex macros, but if you don't use tex's actual parser this is going to be several orders of magnitude slower and probably only write an emulation of a pdf file. As I say above _if_ you specify a grammar for your input (and I could not guess one from the examples posted so far) then you could write a parser for that in lua or emacs lisp or python or whatever. Specifying the grammar will be the hard part, most languages have tools to generate a parser

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is that no you can not do that, and while it would be possible to do something your suggested parse results show that your mental model of TeX's parsing is somehow the reverse of TeX's actual behaviour.

In

```
.... $2^2^n$
```

TeX has consumed the `2^2` and constructed a compound node representing the superscript construct 2^2  before the following `^` has been read from the input buffer or parsed at all.  So when it hits `^` the only natural (non-error) action that TeX could have been programmed to do would be make a superscript on the existing atom, so parsing as `{2^{2}}^{n}`  that is left to right, not right to left.

Similarly `\frac` is a two argument macro that places `#1` over `#2`. So in

```
 \frac\frac12\frac34
```

The first `\frac` gets `\frac` as `'#1` and `1` as `#2`  before the characters `2\frac34` have been tokenized by TeX at all.  Given the macro expansion nature of TeX it is hard to see what it can do given a numerator argument that is just `\frac` and the denominator argument of `1` is not what you intended to be the denominator.

You see the fact the the expression has not been seen by TeX in the error message from

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$\frac\frac12\frac34$
\end{document}
```

which produces

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.5 $\frac\frac1
                2\frac34$
?
```

The line break after 1 is the important information, that shows how much of the input buffer has been read so far.

---

Note the syntax that you suggest is not so far from [asciiimath](http://www.asciimath.org) as you can see from this trial on their test web form

[image]

So taking the asciimath parser and as a pre-processor and generating tex would be a viable possibility.